# MVC 3 Facebook integration error

Tags: facebook, error-handling, integration

I am trying to integrate Facebook log in on my mvc3 website but, whenever I click on the login button it comes up with this:

```
An error occurred. Please try later
```

I am following [this tutorial](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29)

The log in link generated is this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=%7B106425032813017%7D&app_id=%7B106425032813017%7D&client_id=%7B106425032813017%7D&display=popup&domain=localhost&locale=en_US&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df1fc578f9%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A14567%252Ff1e7b8471%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df40e3fefc&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&sdk=joey
```

I have tried other tutorials as well but I get the same error. Even by downloading working source code and changing appId and appSecret I get the same error.

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your token replacement code on your server did not run correctly.

Comment: Look at the HTML that is received by the browser.  Change your code on your server to fix the place where the HTML is incorrect. As you can see in the example link generated, there's some strange characters in the query string parameters